# Conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, gs-conditional-formatting

I can make this work:

I have two cells A1 and B1, and if B1 = A1 I would like the cell to turn green.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make it generic enough when I copy the formatting for the rest of the column (b2:b100) that it works.  Currently it well check the current cell vs A1 all the way down the column.

Im sure this is possible, but google's help documents weren't helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this got it to work

Custom formula is:
=(B1=A1)*(B1<>"")
   background color: Green
   range ... B:B